# l'hopital's rule for expression involving square root

Tags: limits

Dear Colleagues, 
                I've been trying to apply l'Hopital's rule to find a limit, but have so far been defeated. Unfortunately, I'm not even clear on what general strategy to apply to get an answer.

I'm trying to solve : $\lim_{s \to 0} f(s)$ and $\lim_{s \to 0} \frac{d f(s)}{ds}$

for $f(s)= \frac{A_1(s)}{A_2(s)^{1/2}}$,

$$A_2(s) = \frac{2C}{\epsilon(1-\epsilon^2)}[(1-s)^{(1+\epsilon)} -1 + (1+\epsilon)s-\frac{\epsilon(1+\epsilon)}{2}s^2]-\frac{2D}{\epsilon(1+\epsilon)(2+\epsilon)}[1-(1-s)^{2+\epsilon} - (2+\epsilon)s+\frac{\epsilon(1+\epsilon)(2+\epsilon)}{2}s^2]$$

and

$$A_1(s) = \frac{C}{\epsilon(1-\epsilon)}[1-(1-s)^\epsilon -\epsilon s]-\frac{D}{\epsilon(1+\epsilon)}[(1-s)^{1+\epsilon} - 1 + (1+\epsilon)s]$$

One should note that $A_2'(s)=2A_1(s)$ and that $A_1''(0)=C-D$. My attempts to apply l'Hopital's rule haven't got me very far because of a pesky $A_2(s)^{1/2}$ term. For instance

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{s \to 0} f(s) & = \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{A_1(s)}{A_2(s)^{1/2}} \\
                & = \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{A_1'(s)}{\frac{1}{2}A_2(s)^{-1/2}A_2'(s)}\\
                & = \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{A_1'(s)}{A_2(s)^{-1/2}A_1(s)}
\end{align}$$

While I can differentiate the $A_1(s)$ term until I reach a constant (for $s=0$), differentiating the $A_2(s)^{1/2}$ term always generates a fresh $A_2(s)^{-1/2}A_1(s)$ term whose convergence I am unable to determine. Can anyone see a way out?

Thanks in advance, RL

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive attempt from a calculus beginner. Please feel free to point out my mistakes (and I am sure there will be some).

Observe that $A_2(0) = 0, A_1^{'}(0) = 0, A_1(0) = 0$ and hence $A_2^{'}(0) = 0$. Since $A_2^{\frac{1}{2}}(s) = \sqrt{A_2(s)}$, then we can work on $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ now.

$\huge lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(s) = \frac{A_1^{'}(s)A_2^{\frac{1}{2}}(s)}{A_1(s)}$. By L'Hopital Rule, because both $A_1^{'}(s)$ and $A_1(s)$ will converge to $0$ when $s \rightarrow 0$, hence, after differentiating the top and the bottom, we have $\huge lim_{s \rightarrow 0}f(s) = \frac{A_1^{''}(s)A_2^{\frac{1}{2}}(s) + \frac{1}{2}A_2^{-\frac{1}{2}}A_1^{'}(s)A_2^{'}(s)}{A_1^{'}(s)} = \frac{A_1^{''}(s)A_2(s)+\frac{1}{2}A_1^{'}(s)A_2^{'}(s)}{A_1^{'}(s)A_2^{\frac{1}{2}}(s)} = \frac{A_1^{''}(s)A_2(s) + A_1(s)A_1^{'}(s)}{A_1^{'}(s)A_2^{\frac{1}{2}}(s)}$. Again both the top and bottom converge to $0$ as $s$ does. Apply L'Hopital's Rule again:

$\huge \frac{A_1^{'''}(s)A_2(s) + A_1{''}(s)A_2{'}(s) + (A_1^{'}(s))^2 + A_1(s)A_1^{''}(s)}{A_1^{''}(s)A_2^{\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{1}{2}A_2^{-\frac{1}{2}}(s)A_1^{'}(s)} = \frac{A_1^{'''}(s)A_2(s) + (A_1^{'}(s))^2 + 3A_1(s)A_1^{''}(s)}{A_1^{''}(s)A_2^{\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{1}{2}A_2^{-\frac{1}{2}}(s)A_1^{'}(s)} = A_2^{\frac{1}{2}}(s) \frac{A_1^{'''}(s)A_2(s) + (A_1^{'}(s))^2 + 3A_1(s)A_1^{''}(s)}{A_1^{''}(s)A_2(s) + \frac{1}{2}A_1^{'}(s)}$

Once again both the top and the bottom converge to $0$. Apply L'Hopital's Rule and then we can observe that the next result will have $A_1^{''}(s)$ in the denominator, which cause the denominator not to converge to $0$ but in the nominator, we have $A_2^{-\frac{1}{2}}(s)$, which will converge to infinity. Hence I believe $lim_{s \rightarrow 0} f(s)$ does not exist.

$\huge \frac{df(s)}{ds} = \frac{A_1^{'}(s)A_2^{\frac{1}{2}}(s) - \frac{1}{2}A_2^{-\frac{1}{2}}(s)A_1(s)A_2^{'}(s)}{A_2(s)} = \frac{A_1^{'}(s)A_2(s) - \frac{1}{2}A_1(s)A_2^{'}(s)}{A_2^{\frac{3}{2}}(s)} = \frac{A_1^{'}(s)A_2(s) - A_1^{2}(s)}{A_2^{\frac{3}{2}}(s)}$.

Apply L'Hopital's Rule again, we have

$\huge \frac{A_1^{''}(s)A_2(s) + A_1^{'}(s)A_2^{'}(s) - 2A_1(s)A_1^{'}(s)}{\frac{3}{2}A_2^{\frac{1}{2}}(s)} = \frac{A_1^{''}(s)A_2(s)}{\frac{3}{2}A_2^{\frac{1}{2}}(s)}$.

When $s \rightarrow 0$, this limit converge to $0$ and hence $\huge lim_{s \rightarrow 0} \frac{df(s)}{ds} = 0$

Comment: Thanks for looking at the problem, Sanae. Regarding $\lim_{s \to 0} f(s)$ you are right that if you apply L'Hopital's rule to the last expression the denominator goes to a constant and $A_2(s)^{-1/2}$ will go to infinity as $s \to 0 $. But the numerator also goes to zero which still leaves you with the indeterminate form $\infty \times 0$.

Comment: You are right. I feel like I have to keep multiplying $A_2^{\frac{1}{2}}(s)$ to the top and the bottom and there is no end....  I am only confident the answer of the limit of $f’(s)$ is correct.

Comment: I also see a problem with your solution to $\lim_{s \to 0} f'(s)$ The last line makes the following assumption: $$ \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{A_1^{''}(s)A_2(s) + A_1^{'}(s)A_2^{'}(s) - 2A_1(s)A_1^{'}(s)}{\frac{3}{2}A_2^{\frac{1}{2}}(s)} = \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{A_1^{''}(s)A_2(s)} {\frac{3}{2}A_2^{\frac{1}{2}}(s)} + \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{A_1^{'}(s)A_2^{'}(s)} {\frac{3}{2}A_2^{\frac{1}{2}}(s)} - \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{2A_1(s)A_1^{'}(s)}{\frac{3}{2}A_2^{\frac{1}{2}}(s)}$$ To my knowledge, one is generally not allowed to break up limits like this.

Comment: The solution for $\lim_{s \to 0} f'(s)$ also relies on the solution to $\lim_{s \to 0} f(s)$, which we still don't have.

Comment: Here I replaced $A_2^{'}(s)$ by $2A_1(s)$ and then the latter two terms are cancelled. I will spend some time on the first limit later.

Comment: I see. Your solution for $\lim{s \to 0} \frac{d f(s)}{ds}$ is indeed correct.